# Django SECRET_KEY on VPS

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, gitignore, secret-key

I'm working on a Djnago app that needs to be uploaded on a VPS. I already have moved my SECRET_KET from settings.py and placed it inside .env file that I created and addedthis .env file to .gitignore.

When I'm uploading the project to my VPS, Django isn't able to locate my SECRET_KEY because obviously the .env file is not found inside my project directory on the VPS.

What should I do in this case and how am I supposed to call the SECRET_KEY on the server?

Comment: simply you need to add `.env` file or add environment variables

Comment: you should check your virtual environment is launched properly on your VPS

Comment: @MojixCoder would they be secured if i uploaded them on the VPS?

Comment: I think you have your own user on vps so i don't think if anyone has access but you

Comment: @MojixCoder alright bro thx.

Comment: it is fine to use your secret key in .env file or virtual environment variables. the reason that we don't push them in github because the repo is public. if the repo is private you can push your .env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that immediately comes to my mind would be rather than upload your project to the server, you could pull it down onto the server via git.

I'm assuming you are using GitHub to host your code, in which case you can create a read only Deploy Key (see **https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys**) & use that to authenticate your server with your GitHub Repo.

You could then create a `.env` file in your project folder on the server & it won't be overwritten because it's in your .gitignore file.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm pulling my project to the VPS from a Github repository. So, what I understand here is that I should create the .env file on the VPS. But is this considered safe and best practice?

Comment: Depends on how much you trust your provider. Most have decent configuration and will have isolated your files from other users, so I would say it is safe enough.

Another option would have to have your env vars in a secrets store such as Hashicorp's Vault & your application load them in at runtime

TL;DR having a .env file in your project dir on the server in 99% of cases will be fine

Comment: thank you very much. appreciate your advice